# How to access delegate method from another class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, subview

I have a method in my delegate that does this:

```
-(void)showAddingPersonalDetails; {
personal = [[AddingPersonalDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddingWithPersonalDetails" bundle:nil];
[window addSubview:personal.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
mainscreen.view.hidden = YES;
NSLog(@"Called");
}
```

I don't want this view initialized until I need it.  That's why put in in a method.

The problem is, I can't seem to access this code from another class.

I even tried this:

```
BitWiseAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BitWiseAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.showAddingPersonalDetails;
```

But it doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: There shouldn't be a `;` before the `{`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with following code;

```
BitWiseAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BitWiseAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate showAddingPersonalDetails];
```

or

```
[(BitWiseAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] showAddingPersonalDetails];
```